# ng-typeahead is not showing results

Tags: angular, abp

I'm working with abp 5.0 and angular. I was fighting with this problem a lot of hours and I don't know where is the issue. I'm using Dynamic form extension. (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Dynamic-Form-Extensions)

This is my code:

```
    export const DEFAULT_PETS_CREATE_FORM_PROPS = FormProp.createMany<PetDto>([
    {
    type: ePropType.Typeahead,
    name: 'breedId',
    displayName: '::Breed',
    id: 'breedid',
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
    autocomplete: 'off',
    options: (data, text) => {
      const service = data.getInjected(SpecieService);
      const component = data.getInjected(PetComponent);
      let specieId = component.form.get("specieId").value;

      return service.search({specieId: specieId, query: text})
        .pipe(
          map( data => 
            data.map(
              item => ({key: item.name, value: item.id})
            )
          )
        );
    }
  }]);
```

When I type in the field, the service call is executed and it returns data but nothing appears as spected.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: How to install abp in angular app ?

Comment: @GRD https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CLI-New-Command-Samples#angular

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to ABP. It is due to the default `z-index` of the `ng-typeahead` dropdown. To solve it I added this to my CSS:

```css
body > ngb-typeahead-window.dropdown-menu.show {
  z-index: 1056;
}
```